# Nuxt.js: 404 code in production on some dynamic routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

My Nuxt project has around 700-1000 static and dynamic pages hosted via Netlify. ~300 of them are generated correctly.

In production, I discovered that certain dynamically generates routes get a HTTP 404 status code. However, they are generated and loaded without any other error in production. They just get the 404 error code which has bad implications for SEO. Dev server and running the generated `dist` folder via `nuxt start` locally both show no 404 code on those pages. Static generated pages work fine.

Here are my settings for nuxt.config.js (see full list below)

```
  target: 'static',

  generate: {
    fallback: true, 
    ....
  }
```

I do not specify the dynamic routes on generate() because of the [nuxt crawler](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#crawler) .

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "generate_coin_list_file": "node scripts/generate_coin_list.js",
    "generate_coin_images": "node scripts/download_coin_images.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.14.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "frontmatter-markdown-loader": "^3.7.0",
    "ipx": "^0.9.4",
    "lite-youtube-embed": "^0.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-jsonld": "^1.5.3",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-disqus": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.6.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

I am not sure where to look for since this error does not seem to follow a pattern. Because I can generate it locally without the error it could be **problem with Netlify**. What do you guys think of this? Thank you!

**Example:**
_slug.vue

```js
export default {
  name: 'BlogSlug',
  async asyncData({ $content, params, route, error }) {
    let author = {}

    let article = await $content('articles', { deep: true })
      .where({
        slug: params.slug,
      })
      .fetch()
      .catch(() => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
      })

    article = article[0]

    const allArticles = await $content('articles', {
      deep: true,
    })
      .sortBy('date', 'desc')
      .limit(6)
      .fetch()
      .catch(() => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
      })

    if (article.author) {
      author = await $content('authors')
        .where({
          id: article.author,
        })
        .fetch()
        .catch(() => {
          error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
        })
    }
    return { article, allArticles, author }
  },
...
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
import coinList from './data/coin_list.json'

export default {
  target: 'static',

  head: {
    title: 'XXXXXX',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'de',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:card',
        property: 'twitter:card',
        content: 'summary_large_image',
      },
    ],
    link: [
      {
        hid: 'apple-touch-icon',
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
        sizes: '180x180',
        href: '/favicon.ico',
      },
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    'node_modules/lite-youtube-embed/src/lite-yt-embed.css',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/metadata',
    '~/plugins/youtube.client.js',
    '~/plugins/jsonLd.js',
    { src: '@/plugins/vClickOutside', ssr: false },
    '~/plugins/disqus',
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: [
    '~/components',

    { path: '~/components/utils', extensions: ['vue'] },
    { path: '~/components/global' },
  ],

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    [
      '@nuxt/image',
      {
        provider: 'static',
      },
    ],
    '@/modules/sitemapRouteGenerator.js',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxt/content',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
    // has to be last
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
  ],

  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL,
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
  },

  // GTM Analytics
  gtm: {
    enabled: true,
    pageTracking: true,
  },

  axios: {},

  image: {
    // Options
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com', 'coingecko.com'],
    presets: {
      blog: {
        modifiers: {
          format: 'webp',
        },
      },
    },
  },

  // Content module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-content
  content: {
    // nestedProperties: ['articles.slug'],
  },

  generate: {
    fallback: true,
    async routes() {
      const routes = await _getRoutes()

      async function _getRoutes($content) {
        const paths = []

        coinList.forEach((coin) => {
          paths.push({
            route: `/coins/${coin.id}/historisch/`,
            payload: coin.id,
          })
        })

        return paths
      }

      return routes
    },
  },

  router: {
    routeNameSplitter: '/',
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.md$/,
        loader: 'frontmatter-markdown-loader',
      })
    },
  },
}
```

Module: sitemapRouteGenerator.js

```js
export default function () {
  this.nuxt.hook('generate:done', (context) => {
    const routesToExclude = /\/index|\/articles\/|\/undefined/ // Add any route you don't want in your sitemap. Potentially get this from an .env file.
    const allRoutes = Array.from(context.generatedRoutes)
    // console.log(context.generatedRoutes)

    const routes = allRoutes.filter((route) => !routesToExclude.test(route))

    // console.log(routes)

    this.nuxt.options.sitemap.routes = [...routes]
  })
}
```

Comment: Share us one of your buggy pages. Also, maybe try to host it on Vercel to see if it's specific to Netlify (I doubt).

Comment: i added some examples at the end of the question

Comment: The actual result will not help us debug what is not working. Please submit the actual code of the page itself + any kind of middleware + router guard + modules + global plugins + alike (that may impact the page in any way).

Comment: Kissu, thank you for the help! I hope now I provided more to the issue. I do not have middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The fix was to generate all routes of dynamic pages in the generate hook even though Nuxt states about [the generate crawler](https://content.nuxtjs.org/v1/getting-started/advanced/):

```
Since Nuxt 2.14+, nuxt generate has a crawler feature integrated which will crawl all your links and generate your routes based on those links. Therefore you do not need to do anything in order for your dynamic routes to be crawled.
```

I guess it only works on static pages and partly on dynamic routes (?). Since I used a nested directory structure I had to modify the route path before manually.

```js
  generate: {
    fallback: true,
    async routes() {
      let routes
      const contentRoutes = await _getContentRoutes()

      async function _getContentRoutes() {
        const { $content } = require('@nuxt/content')
        const files = await $content({ deep: true }).only(['path']).fetch()
        return files.map((file) => file.path.replace('/articles/', ''))
      }

      return routes
    },
  },
```

In this example I have some markdown files in content/articles/SOMEARTICLE.md so I had to remove the '/article' from the path. Otherwise nuxt throws an error when generating the routes.

Comment: For me, if you use the `generate` function the crawler is not used anymore. Nice catch!

Comment: I have the identical situation in Nuxt3. So frustrating

Comment: @Sharkfin Did you solve this issue? I am facing it too.